# Query to filter out redundant records from the table

Tags: mysql, sql

The matches table contains data for cricket matches between different teams and the winner.

| Team_1 | Team_2 | Winner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CSK | MI | MI |
| MI | CSK | MI |
| MI | KKR | MI |
| RCB | RR | RR |
| RCB | RR | RR |
| KKR | MI | MI |

Write a query to filter out redundant records from the table (e.g. row 1 and row 2 refers to the same match, so we need to keep only 1 of these rows in resultant table)

How to solve it assuming that the data is not limited to just above values, lets say there are 10 teams. I tried to solve using self join but the team order is also not consistent like RCB VS RR is same in both cases and for others it is reversed.
I am just a beginner with SQL

Comment: *"I tried to solve using"* ...  You are going to get better answers if you post what queries you have attempted and what the outputs were.  Also include and example of your *desired* outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to `unpivot` the columns to have both teams in the same column and we need to add `row_number()` to make sure we're keeping the matches correctly. Then we `pivot` it back using `group by`, but this time we have the duplicates in the correct columns. Then we `select distinct` to get the results we were looking for. It would be simpler if you had game_id or game_date or something like that.

```
with t2 as (
           select Team_1 as team, Winner, row_number() over(order by Team_1) as match_num from   t

           union all

           select Team_2, Winner, row_number() over(order by Team_1) from   t
           )

select     distinct Team_1, Team_2, Winner
from      (
           select   match_num
                   ,max(team)   as Team_1
                   ,min(team)   as Team_2
                   ,max(Winner) as Winner
           from     t2
           group by match_num
          ) t2
```

| Team_1 | Team_2 | Winner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MI | CSK | MI |
| MI | KKR | MI |
| RR | RCB | RR |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1hVpDbVP)